# iCalendar recurring events to front and back end

Tags: javascript, c#, icalendar, rrule

I need calendar with recurring events and easy way to store the information to db and present stored events from db to front end.

I have tried using iCalendar data format with rrule.js at front end and iCal.NET(2.3.5) at back end storing recurrance pattern to db as string with `RecurrencePattern.ToString()` form and parsing the string at front with `rrulestr()`. I would like to store similar patterns like RRuleSet with iCal.NET but it seems to be impossible.

Is there a way to store RRuleSet style string with iCal.NET or some other library or is there better way to handle recurring events from front to back and back to front?